# Delete from command not working in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite db file. I am using DB Browser for Sqlite as the client. I went in and ran delete from command on most of my tables. Thereafter I tried to export using the option Database to SQL file I notice all my data is appearing  in it. What I wondering is that why the data have not been deleted? I know the sqlite file size will not shrink.

Below is snippet of my codes.

```
string str = @"Data Source=" + userFilePath + "\\mysqlite.sqlite3";
                    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(str))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        SQLiteTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();
                        try
                        {


                            String cmdSelect1 = "Select * from table1 where companyID='" + companyID + "' And month='" + month + "' And year='" + year + "'";
                            int fiscalPeriod = Convert.ToInt32(monthNumber);
                            int financialYear = Convert.ToInt32(itemvalueyear);
                            using (SQLiteCommand cmd1 = new SQLiteCommand(cmdSelect1, con, trans))
                            {
                                SQLiteDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

                                if (dr1.Read())
                                {

                                    MessageBoxResult messageBoxResult = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Records Already Exist ? Are you confirm replace it?", "Delete Confirmation", System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
                                    if (messageBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                                    {

                                        String deleteTable = "Delete from table1 where companyID='" + companyID + "' And month='" + month + "' And year='" + year + "'";
                                        using (SQLiteCommand cmdDeleteTb1 = new SQLiteCommand(deleteTable, con, trans))
                                        {
                                            cmdDeleteTb1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                            cmdDeleteTb1.Dispose();
                                        }
                                        foreach (object line in linesC)
                                        {
                                            if (line.GetType() == typeof(TypeC))
                                            {

                                                String cmdText2 = "INSERT INTO table1(tbID,companyID,month,year) VALUES(@tbID,@companyID,@month,@year)";
                                                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(cmdText2, con, trans))
                                                {

                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbID", tbID);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyID", companyID);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month", month);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year);
                                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                                                    cmd.Dispose();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                }


                                dr1.Close();
                                cmd1.Dispose();
                            }
                            trans.Commit();

                            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Inserted Into Database");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Rollback " + ex.ToString());
                            trans.Rollback();
                        }

                        con.Close();
                        con.Dispose();



                        GC.Collect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok:

It appears you are beginning two transactions.  You begin your loop inserts after you begin your delete.

Commit your Delete transaction and then later commit your inserts.

This is  than committing after beginning both transactions.

Comment: I have updated my question with my code snippet. I am not sure where to put the finalise as I am running a transaction. But towards the end I have con.close() and I even had to run GC.collect else I tend to get some errors too. Please advice what I am missing ?

Comment: Ok researched this and after seeing your code came up with something similar by more specific to your Sql.

Comment: Sorry if thisbisnt helpful.  I'm interested to see I'd you solved this.  It's very interesting, I've searched far and high and haven't seen a bipartite transactions (delete section, insert section).  Most ive seen are much more simple.  I'm interested to see what works.  It seems Luke you BEGIN two transactions in the same statement so I'm not sure.  Feed back appreciated, maybe we can help!!

Comment: I am a bit confuse if I split into two transaction then commit the delete first then only the insert wouldnt it be a problem incase my delete goes through and the insert fails? So how to resolve on this? Actually I just begin one transaction that is this  SQLiteTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();. Thereafter both the insert and delete are in the trans transaction if you notice that?